# Detecting right click position on angular leaflet map

Tags: angular-leaflet-directive

I have a mobile page showing a map using [angular-leaflet-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) 0.7.11, and have declared my required events like so:

```
$scope.map = {
    events: [
        'mousedown',
        'contextmenu'
    ],
    ...
}

$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.mousedown', function (event) {
    debugger;
});
```

Where the debugger statement is, the `event` variable contains no information about where the map was clicked. The same `event` format was provided by the directive when the `contextmenu` event is triggered.

In fact, if I inspect the entire `event` variable, it is just an `Object`, not an `Event`:

[image: event]

Are [the docs](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/events) wrong? Is [the example](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0115-basic-events-example.html) missing something? How can I obtain the X/Y *or* Lat/Lng for the particular position that I have right-clicked (tap-hold)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the 'leafletEvent'. Try this:

```
myApp.controller('YourController', ['$scope', 'leafletEvent', function($scope) {

    $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.mousedown', function (event, leafletEvent) {
        leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
            map.on('click', function(e) {
                console.log('e');
                console.log(e);
                console.log('e.latlng:');
                console.log(e.latlng); // L.LatLng {lat: 19.642587534013046, lng: -4.5703125}
            });
        });
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Correct! argument #2 (leafletEvent) is undocumented.